# Script stops on specific command without go into catch block

Tags: c#, exception, powershell, powershell-2.0, powercli

I have a powershell script with PowerCLI commands to install and configure virtual machines.

These are the settings in the environment

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- ESX 4.1
- PowerShell v2
- PowerCLI 5.1

The script will be triggered from a user on a website. Following code start the script.
PathToScript is a UNC path

```
const string Path32BitPowerShell = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";

public static void Run32BitPowerShell(String PathToScript, Boolean WaitForExit, String Arguments = "")
{
    Process PowerShellProcess = new Process();
    PowerShellProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    PowerShellProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    PowerShellProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path32BitPowerShell;
    PowerShellProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
    PowerShellProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = PathToScript + " " + Arguments;

    PowerShellProcess.Start();

    if (WaitForExit)
    {
        PowerShellProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

The script has this two global settings:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$ConfirmPreference = "None"
```

The whole code is inside a try block with catch/finally
But the code never goes into the catch block. I know it because I wrote one time as first line in the catch block `Stop-Computer -Force -Confirm:$false` and the webserver was still running after 5 minutes after the script was finished.

The code stops on the command [Invoke-VMScript](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI51/html/Invoke-VMScript.html):

```
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VM -ScriptType Bat -ScriptText "powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser" -GuestUser "***" -GuestPassword "****"
```

The exit code from the C# process is `1`

**Important:**

The script runs perfectly, wenn I start it interactive (from the ISE) !
The issue only occurs when the webserver starts it (non-interactive).

Someone has any idea, where the problem could be ?

/Update

It works also directly from the powershell command line, but also interactive

Comment: Sounds like an authorization/rights issue to me. Does the iis user have enough rights to start it?

Comment: Yes, the application pool identity is set to a generic domain user. He has special permission in the ESX environment.
When I login with his credentials and run the script with the ISE, it works as expected.

Comment: _To run Invoke-VMScript, the user must have read access to the folder containing the virtual machine and a Virtual Machine.Interaction.Console Interaction privilege._ Checked?

Comment: Yes, the user has this right, also when triggered from the website (right heredity), the connect to the ESX server use the credentials from the user which run the script. this is the generic account (Application pool identity)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

$Global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$Global:ConfirmPreference = 'None'

Worked for me when I had very similar problem.